# Rails duplicate entries on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, duplicates

I have a website that keeps track of which songs are played on the radio. Since changed my song from `belongs_to :artist` to `has_many :artists` I'm seeing duplicate entries in the playlist model where a song has multiple artists. The number of duplicate entries is equal to the number of artists.

Here's the setup:

```
# models/playlist.rb
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song
  has_many :artists, through: :song
  belongs_to :radiostation
  validate :today_unique_playlist_item
end

# models/song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :playlists
  has_many :radiostations, through: :generalplaylists
  has_many :artists_songs
  has_many :artists, through: :artists_songs
end

# models/artist.rb
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :artists_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :artists_songs
  has_many :playlists, through: :songs
  has_many :radiostations, through: :playlists
end

# models/artist_songs.rb
class ArtistsSong < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :song
end
```

I've added a custom validation on the playlist to check for the uniqueness. The RSpec tests run perfectly but still there a duplicate entries. So my guess is that is has to be a database issue. I'm using PostgreSQL.

```
# custom validation
def today_unique_playlist_item
  exisiting_record = Generalplaylist.joins(:song, :radiostation).where('songs.id = ? AND time = ? AND radiostations.id = ? AND generalplaylists.created_at > ?', song_id, time, radiostation_id, 1.day.ago).present?
  errors.add(:base, 'none unique playlist') if exisiting_record
end
```

> Side note: I'm only fetching the last day since the current broadcast time (attribute `playlist.time`) doesn't have the date. Current format: `22:00`

I'm thinking to but an index on the playlist model in the schema but not sure if that will fix the issue and what to put there.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Shouldn't a Playlist have many Songs?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is probably that custom validation is running a select on the database before inserting a record.

This means that if two concurrent validations run, they will both see no unique record and move on to the next line of code which is probably inserting the record, causing duplicate inserts.

I would recommend using [Active Record Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) and instead of doing that check, set a unique constraint on the `Playlist` and do an upsert.